# Laravel - Disable option value after selecting it once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5

I have a form in my project that a user is using to fill up an application.
In this form I have a table with details about user's language skill.
Also, in my project I have a seeder with all the languages that are shown in an option select in the table.

How can I disable one of the languages after it has been selected once?

This are some samples of my code:

HTML:

```
<td id="resource_profile_languages">
  <select {{ (FALSE == $canEdit) ? 'readonly':'' }} class="form-control form-select" id="{{ 'resource_profile_language_'.$index }}" name="{{ 'resource_profile_language_'.$index }}" placeholder="Language">
    @foreach($languages as $r=>$language)
      <option {{ ($language->name == $resourceProfileLanguage->language->name) ? 'selected':'' }} value="{{ $language->value }}" >{{ $language->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
</td>
```

this is my script way of adding a new language in the table:

```
function addNewLanguage(){
    var count = $('#resource_profile_language_table').children('tr').length;

    var select_language = $('#resource_profile_languages')
                            .children([CONST_ENGLISH_ID])
                            .clone()
                            .attr('id', idResourceProfileLanguage.concat(count))
                            .attr('name', idResourceProfileLanguage.concat(count));


    $('#resource_profile_language_table').append($('<tr>').append( $('<td id="resource_profile_languages_' + count + '" name="resource_profile_languges_' + count + '">').append(select_language)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for a `change` event in the select. Since the select's ID is dynamic, you can use Blade syntax as long as it's inline/included to the template.  Something like:

```
$("#{{ 'resource_profile_language_'.$index }}").on("change", function(){
     $("#{{ 'resource_profile_language_'.$index }} option:selected").attr("disabled","disabled")
    .siblings();
 });
```